# How to automatically pull in Win32 API declarations in C#?

Tags: c#, winapi

I am searching for a way that will automate adding declarations of Win32 API functions in C# code. For example, I currently have to add:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string path);
```

when I want to call `LoadLibrary`. And similar for every other function that I want to call.

Is there some list of all these Win32 declarations already so that I don't have to keep adding them myself? Or some other "correct" way of doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look into [PInvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/) and its Visual Studio plugin.

Comment: Thanks! That is a start. Any idea how to install PInvoke.net in Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 3):

On the site http://pinvoke.net/ you can find a free plugin for Visual Studio for adding pinvoke signatures.